# Changing a text to time in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a column which is imported as text. How can I go about altering the datatype as time from text in postgres?

Please help.

Comment: Do you want the data type `time` or do you actually want [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)?

Comment: I wanted time but i can't add a time column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what i did was this:

The time is always an issue in any database when converted from text to date. I did the following as i could not find a direct solution

1. I created a new column "visit_time" of time type and copied all the time that are in text column to the new column
2. The code is as below:

   ```
      ALTER TABLE "ae" ADD COLUMN visit_time time;

      UPDATE "ae" SET visit_time = to_timestamp(visit_time2,'HH24:MI:SS');;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Google postgres string to timestamp suggests  [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: "It does not work" is useless. Post the SQLrequest and the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table <table>
alter <columnname> type time
using <columnname>::time;
```

if it's not a straight conversion.. you can also write a function to handle this...

```
alter table <table>
alter <columnname> type time
using fn_someconversionfunction(<columnname>);
```